# How can I put tabs in the same row as the header in React Material-UI? (codesandbox included)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-v1pyw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am trying to put the tabs along with the header

[image]

So that the tabs are next to the title.

What I did was adding the tabs inside the `AppBar` component,

```
<AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
  <Toolbar>
    <IconButton
      edge="start"
      color="inherit"
      onClick={handleClose}
      aria-label="close"
    >
      <CloseIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
      Sound
    </Typography>
  </Toolbar>

  <Tabs
    variant="fullWidth"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-label="nav tabs example"
  >
    <LinkTab label="Page One" href="/drafts" {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <LinkTab label="Page Two" href="/trash" {...a11yProps(1)} />
    <LinkTab label="Page Three" href="/spam" {...a11yProps(2)} />
  </Tabs>
</AppBar>
```

But it seems like they cannot fit inside the header.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add them within the Toolbar:

```
    <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          edge="start"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={handleClose}
          aria-label="close"
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
          Sound
        </Typography>
        <Tabs
          variant="fullWidth"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="nav tabs example"
        >
          <LinkTab label="Page One" href="/drafts" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <LinkTab label="Page Two" href="/trash" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <LinkTab label="Page Three" href="/spam" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Toolbar>          
    </AppBar>
```

which looks like this:
[image]